# .htaccess in development mode / friendly URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using development URL `http://localhost/demo/version2`, in this folder I have primary project.

I want to access `http://localhost/demo/version2/**en/1**`
where rewrite parameters are `index.php?lang=en&item=1` etc.

I'm using .htaccess

```
# enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also the .htaccess is then used in `web2.domain.com` and needs to work there too.

In current configuration the system is not working (infinite loops), also in real environment with `web2.domain.com/en` the web is not properly displayed.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/version2/([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ index.php?lang=$1&item=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: In that case Rewrite rule i think is not doing anything
---SERVER RESPONSE:
Not Found

The requested URL /demo/version2/en/1 was not found on this server.